# C++: Trouble Using String as Argument of a Function

Tags: c++, function, char, constants, arguments

Okay, I am having trouble with the following piece of code (in a header file):

```
#ifndef XML_H_INCLUDED
#define XML_H_INCLUDED
#include "libxml/parser.h"
#include "libxml/xmlwriter.h"
#include <string>


class XmlFile{
public:
    XmlFile(string filename){
        file = xmlParseFile(filename);


    }
    xmlDocPtr file; //Pointer to xml file


};



#endif // XML_H_INCLUDED
```

The file is including in the main source file (but is not accessed, so its contents are not important).

I keep getting the following error (In Codeblocks):

```
error: cannot convert 'std::string' to 'const char*' 
for argument '1' to 'xmlDoc* xmlParseFile(const char*)'|
```

I have run into this many times, and it is driving me crazy.

I would prefer not to use vectors if possible (adds another step in initializing the function.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried looking this up, but have not found any satisfactory answers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
file = xmlParseFile(filename.c_str());
```

Comment: I should add that that line of code works fine, but I am curious as to what exactly it does (so I can avoid similar mistakes in the future). Is it simply a function defined in "String" that returns the string? How does it get around the const char* problem?

Comment: @Biosci3c, std::string has a method c_str() which returns a const char*.  The xmlParseFile expects a const char* (just like the compiler error says)...not a std::string.

Comment: It returns a `const char*` which points to the null-terminated sequences of characters that make up that string.  A normal 'C' string, hence the name of the method.

Comment: Ah, thanks, makes sense. Ok, that answers my question. Wow, you guys are fast. :)     Could have saved myself so much trouble earlier.

Comment: @Biosci3c, also your XmlFile constructor should be changed to... XmlFile(const string& filename).  That avoids making a copy of the string and also communicates to anyone using your class that you do not alter its value.

Comment: @dgnorton, I don't need the string to be a constant, but it just seems to demand that I pass a const char*

Comment: @Biosci3c - That the libxml function takes a `const char*` parameter is a contract with the caller that the characters pointed to won't be modified. dgnorton is suggesting (quite reasonably) that you should offer users of your XmlFile class the same contract. If you don't NEED to modify the string, then it's good practice to declare that intent by using `const string&`.

Comment: @Biosci3c, it's best practice to use `const` in that way.  Don't have enough room in a comment to do the topic justice.  Read up on it here ... [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html).  I would also suggest a couple books: ["Effective C++" by Scott Meyers](http://goo.gl/qtGF) and ["C++ Coding Standards" by Herb Sutter](http://goo.gl/AzfW).